# how to find font awesome icons from that's name

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, font-awesome

I have API and its return the name of fontAwsome icon like below

```
                    "value": 1,
                    "feature": {
                        "title": "WC"
                        "image": " fa-toilet",
                        "VIP": 6,
                    }
```

and I need to change image to Font Awesome Icons

I know one way that is we need create an map and define on that what icon belong to what string
like this

```
Map<String,IconData> icons = {
'fa-toilet': FontAwesomeIcons.toilet
};
```

but I need another way

HELP plz

Comment: Dart is a statically typed language and doesn't support reflection. so the only simple way you can do is by mapping it.

Comment: on mapping new problem is that I dont know what's icon use on API
and if API return new String my App get error

Comment: the safe way is to map all possible icons used.

Comment: to loooooong :|

Comment: contributor has provided  how to generate. https://github.com/fluttercommunity/font_awesome_flutter/tree/master/util

Comment: after generated the map, you can use this method https://github.com/fluttercommunity/font_awesome_flutter/issues/244#issuecomment-1610900672

Answer (score 0):

1. [Fork the font_awesome_flutter repository from GitHub](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/font_awesome_flutter/fork)
2. Clone and open the project in your local
3. Run `./util/configurator.sh --dynamic` on terminal
4. Commit and push the changes
5. Depend on your package with [git dependency](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages)
6. Use the icon like this:

   ```
   FaIcon(faIconNameMapping['solid toolbox'])
   ```

Notice that you have to add its style before the icon name (for example, `solid`).

You may also need to build your app with the `--no-tree-shake-icons` flag.

---

Reference:

- [font_awesome_flutter | Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter)

Answer (score 0):

I found something :D

if in API we have unicode of icons we can show its easily
I think its best and easy way

with this function you can change unicode to icon ↓↓

```
ourIcon(String unicode) {

return IconDataSolid(int.parse(unicode,radix: 16));

}
```